# File upload using Threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have written a code to upload a file using thread.I have place a simple file upload control and a button on a page.The code looks like this-

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object,
                               ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim timeStart As TimeSpan = Nothing
    Dim timeEnd As TimeSpan = Nothing
    Dim timeDiff As TimeSpan = Nothing
    Dim ex As Exception = Nothing
    Dim FileNameWithoutExtension As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Dim objTh As Thread = Nothing
        objTh = New Thread(AddressOf SaveFileByBuffering)
        timeStart = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
        objTh.IsBackground = True


        FileNameWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FldUploadThreading.FileName)
        objTh.Start("New_" + FileNameWithoutExtension)
        objTh.Name = "ARAThreadFileBuffer"
        objTh.Join()

        timeEnd = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
        timeDiff = timeEnd - timeStart

    Catch exThAbort As ThreadAbortException
        ex = exThAbort
    Catch exTh As ThreadStartException
        ex = exTh
    Catch exCommon As Exception
        ex = exCommon
    End Try

End Sub
```

the method to be called using thread:

```
Public Function SaveFileByBuffering(ByVal lstrFilePath As String)
    Dim bufferSize As Integer = 512
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}


    Dim pathUrl As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("strFilePath").ToString()

    Dim uploadObj As UploadDetail = New UploadDetail()
    uploadObj.IsReady = True
    uploadObj.FileName = lstrFilePath
    uploadObj.ContentLength = Me.FldUploadThreading.PostedFile.ContentLength

    Me.Session("UploadXDetail") = uploadObj

    Dim Upload As UploadDetail = DirectCast(Me.Session("UploadXDetail"), UploadDetail)

    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(Me.FldUploadThreading.PostedFile.FileName)

    Using fs As New FileStream(Path.Combine(pathUrl, lstrFilePath), FileMode.Create)
        While Upload.UploadedLength < Upload.ContentLength
            Dim bytes As Integer = Me.FldUploadThreading.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes)
            Upload.UploadedLength += bytes
        End While
    End Using
End Function
```

There are two issues:

1. When some one clicks on the same button simultaneously the thread behavior works in a different way , some time page crashes.
2. When this process i have tested on multiuser environment with 60 users and file size is 25 MB each user the page crashed.

I have .net 3.5 so i have no choice with advance version of file upload in 2010 or later version.

Comment: That is not c#, please use the correct tags and do not put them in the title

Comment: Any error given when the page crashed?

Comment: And this is ASP.Net, too?

Comment: Turn both `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` on. You should see that the line `objTh = New Thread(AddressOf SaveFileByBuffering)` is invalid because that method requires a parameter.

Comment: The Error mesaage is like-

Comment: Hi svranken ,The Error mesaage is like-   1-File uploding is more than 15 minutes but still in progress  2- Internet explorer cannot explore the page -Diagnose Internet problems 3- some user get login probem to the server on which the site has hosted               ----------------------Chris-I have passed the parameters in the thread.start(filename)